# How to remove specific e-mail from published wordpress comments?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a couple thousands published comments from one author on my site. Now i need to remove e-mail adress from ALL of this comments, without removing comments itself. How can i do it? Help plz

Comment: Hint: `wp_comments` has a field called `comment_author_email`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score -2):

Please access database and remove email address.

Comment: help me with creating mysql query please. Just template

Comment: Through phpMyAdmin you can do